# Gson How to covert json to Custom Class

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

> Somary for below: I need to deserilize `A<B<C>>` from json with Java Gson library

I have an api that response in this templete (Json):

```
{code:string, message:string, data:(any json type/object/array)}
```

In Java I define a class to read results:

```
public class ApiResult <DATA> {
    public String code;
    public String message;
    public DATA data;
}
```

And I have another Data Class:

```
public class Ball {
    public String color;
    public String weight;
}
```

One of my api methods returns list of ball in top template.
I use `GSON.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<ApiResult<List<Ball>>>() {}.getType());`

But Gson read data in  `List<com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap>` not List

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a full sample JSON?

Comment: Yes, I think I had the same problem once... Try declaring a `public class BallListApiResult extends ApiResult<List<Ball>>` - I am quite confident that this should work (as I have the exact same structure in a project), but I cannot explain why your way does not... Would be cool if someone could...

Comment: The other problem is I have many datas not only Ball and ... (Because my api structure for every api methods I have different datas and by your way I need many Custom Extra Classes to catch them)

Comment: Yes, but each of these classes is only a few lines - we also have about 30 subclasses of our `AbstractResponse<T>`. But did you try it? Does it work?

Comment: In my current project, I have a method to analyze response 'code' and then return `data`. If I can make Class<A<T>> class from Class<T> and pass it to GSON.fromJson(reader, clazz) exept GSON.fromJson(reader,type) it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve my question  but not for all `A<B<C>>` problems

I redefine my `ApiResult` class to:

```
public class ApiResult {
    public String code;
    public String message;
    public JsonElement data; 
}
```

Using `result = GSON.fromJson(reader, ApiResult.class);` I extract global response (All api responses return this part).
and check `code` and `message` that I need

then I extract real data  I want with `final List<Ball> data = GSON.fromJson(result.data, new TypeToken<List<Ball>>() {}.getType());` and return it

I think the main bug/limit in Gson is it only check Generic Type only once for parent type and doesn't check it for generic Type[s]

and I think it's better that they (its Developers) add it to next versions